# How to compile OPENSSL (RSA,DSA,HMAC) in Windows Kernel Driver?

Tags: c, windows, cryptography, openssl, kernel

I want to compile openssl mostly RSA, DSA and HMAC in windows kernel driver. Basically i want to extract the given algorithm and compile only them. Has it been done? or are there any alternates?

Answer (score 2):

Please explain what you mean by "mostly RSA, ..." and "in windows kernel driver".

OpenSSL is *cryptographic software*. The algorithms within are fragile, in that minor mistakes in how they are used can have catastrophic results. So, unless you *really* know what you are doing (and in that case you wouldn't be asking here, now would you?) to keep your fingers firmly seated in your pockets.

Perhaps [NaCL](http://rdist.root.org/2009/07/14/nacl-djbs-new-crypto-library/) is nearer to what you need? Or some other cryptographic library?

Comment: Is there RSA or DSA in NaCL Crypto library?

Comment: @vonbrand: Sorry for not being so clear. I want to implement RSA Algorithm (including few other) in kernel driver. I don't want to compile complete openssl package, I just want to extract few algorithms from it's source code and compile it in kernel mode.

Comment: You want to add the algorithms in a driver to Windows? Aren't they implemented there somewhere already? What would be the use of this? Can whatever you want to do be done by regular userland programs?

Comment: Basically I want communication between my User Mode Application and Kernel Driver totally encrypted. It will need encryption/decryption code on both sides. RSA will be needed to exchange keys between usermode app and kernel mode driver. Then AES enc will be used and the key exchanged will be used to enc/decrypt data passed between app and kernel mode driver.

Comment: If "somebody" can intercept system calls and data exchanged between the kernel and userland, the game is _long_ over...

Comment: It can be intercepted. Check these progs: http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=199
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/device_io_view.html

Comment: And if somebody install kernel mode hook, your encryption will be.....nothing. :)

Comment: @Xearinox: I am willing to take this chance. but will try to protect my app to most extent.

Comment: @CasperGhost, are you sure this is the measure that gives you most bang for the buck (most security gain for your work)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing exactly what you're saying: extracting the algorithms I need from OpenSSl to a small and compact library. It can be done and it's, according to my experience, a very painful process. You'll end up being forced to include more modules than you expected. Due to lack of documentation, you also need to go through the source code to understand module functionality most of the time. My suggestion is: don't do this unless you have no alternative.